# How do we make an ellipsis accessible in pagination?

Tags: html, pagination, accessibility

I'm trying to make a pagination module accessible. I'm feeling pretty good about it, but not sure how to deal with the ellipsis that's used to indicate we're skipping a bunch of pages.

My instinct is to include some explanatory text inside a "visually-hidden" span, as I've done here.

```html
<nav aria-label="pagination">
  <ul class="pagination__list">
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <a href="#"><span class="visually-hidden">Page </span>1</a>
    </li>
    <!-- skipping pages 2 - 10 to keep things manageable -->
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <span class="pagiantion__skip-indicator"><span class="visually-hidden">Skipping pages 2 to 10</span>&hellip;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <a href="#"><span class="visually-hidden">Page </span>11</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <a href="#"><span class="visually-hidden">Page </span>12</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ti_pagination__item">
      <a href="#" class="active" aria-current="page"><span class="visually-hidden">Page </span>13</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <a href="#"><span class="visually-hidden">Page </span>14</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <a href="#"><span class="visually-hidden">Page </span>15</a>
    </li>
    <!-- skipping pages 16-99 to keep things manageable -->
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <span class="pagiantion__skip-indicator"><span class="visually-hidden">Skipping pages 16 to 99</span>&hellip;</span>
    </li>
    <!-- Last page -->
    <li class="pagination__item">
      <a href="#"><span class="visually-hidden">Page </span>100</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm hoping somebody can let me know if this is the best lemonade to make with this situation, or point me at some good resources.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same issue recently and after considering a couple of options similar to the one in your code I came up with this one: using **role="img"** with an **aria-label="ellipses"** for the visually hidden element that contains the ellipsis.

It would be:

```
<li class="skiped-pages">
   <span class="sr-only" role="img" aria-label="ellipses">...</span>
</li>
```

Most screen readers will read "..." as a long pause, even if it is used outside the context of a paragraph. That's why I've added the aria-label with the word "ellipses", not too verbose and meaningfull enough for the purpose of a hiatus indicator.

The purpose of the role="img" is to allow the use of an aria-label (it wont be read out by screen readers when used in `<span>` or `<li>`). It's presented as an image by screen readers which is semantically OK for me as "..." is actually some sort of symbol or icon standing for an ellipsis (in my case I replace the ellipses with a fancy long line via CSS). For example NVDA (v. 2017 with Chrome 79/FFox 57) reads *"link: page 15"*, *"Image: ellipses"*, *"link: page 100"*. See how the mental model is similar to the one you would present in the visual design.

Thinking about progressive enhancement, I would use "..." inside the visually-hidden element text as any word would look weird before styles.

---

When looking for resources for backing up this answer I've noticed MDN docs make a similar point with emojis in their third use case here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Role_Img

Comment: Conveying the ellipsis with a visually-hidden element and hiding the visual ellipsis from screen readers would be a better approach, imo, because that avoids an unexpected announcement of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are targeting people  with cognitive disabilities, a text alternative for ellipsis in page navigation appears quite superfluous, as it's a perfectly common thing.

Listening "Skipping pages 16 to 99" would be quite annoying as it provides an information that people can deduce by themselves

Providing an input field to jump to a specified page might be a more useful addition.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use a visually-hidden element to convey the ellipsis, like what you've done. I would also suggest audially hiding the HTML entity of ellipsis with `aria-hidden="true"`. So the code would be:

```
<span class="visually-hidden">Ellipsis</span><span aria-hidden="true">&hellip;</span>
```

Your writing `Skipping pages 16 to 99` in the visually-hidden element is also fine to me.